# Run command on upgrade of certain package

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg, deb, execute-command

I am trying to automate an action so that it runs after a file in a certain package is upgraded.

On Arch I can put a file in `/usr/share/libalpm/hooks` that specifies the package, file that is updated, and command to run when it is updated.

Is there a way to do something similar with dpkg (when a package is upgraded and a file changes, run a command on the file)?

I would not be able to modify the package being installed.